# Can I import text from a pdf file to display in HTML with the same styles using visual studio 2010?

Tags: html, text, styling

I started working for a company where the client sends us visual examples of the pages they want (with lots of text in different fonts) and we incorporate that into the site we build for them. This takes up lots of time as we need to style everything to be almost exactly the same. I am looking for a quicker way to do this. can someone please help? any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found converter from PDF to HTML online, so you won't need to download anything.
I didn't used it yet, but maybe It's working

http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf-to-html/

But you can also use

`<iframe href="pdf_file.pdf" width="500" height="200"></iframe>`

And PDF file will be shown in frame in your browser using Adobe PDF reader.

Comment: From what I can gather, the OP wants to _convert_ a PDF into HTML, not simply display it